# How can I ensure that my python Code Registers the row1 2 or 3 under a different segment of Code?

Tags: python

```
value = [10 ,20 ,50 ,100]
Balance = 0
Change = 0
totalCoins = 0
print("|~~~~~~~~~|")
print("|~~~Jack~~|")
print("|~~Blacks~|")
print("|~~Food~~~|")
print("|~~~And~~~|")
print("|~~Drink~~|")
print("|~Machine~|")

print("Row 1 ~ Crisps")
print("A1 is Walkers Crisps")
print("B1 is Pringles")
print("C1 is Lays")
print("Row 2 ~ Drinks")
print("A2 is Diet Coke")
print("B2 is Crystal Pepsi")
print("C2 is Sprite")
print("Row 3 ~ Sweets")
print("A3 is Cadbury's Chocolate")
print("B3 is Strawberry Laces")
print("C3 is Haribo")
CoinAmount = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop")
if CoinAmount == "Yes" or "YES":
  Balance = int(input("Enter the total value of your Coins in P, Note: Machine only accepts 10p, 20p, 50p £1coins however you Must put the amount you want in Pennies either 10, 20, 50, 100,: "))
  totalCoins = Balance + totalCoins
  print ('You now have a total Balance of' ,totalCoins ,'P')
  CoinAmount = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop")
elif Balance != value:
    print("Machine doesn't accept these total coins")
while CoinAmount == "Yes":
    Balance = int(input("Enter the total value of your Coins in P, Note: Machine only accepts 10p, 20p, 50p £1coins however you Must put the amount you want in Pennies either 10, 20, 50, 100,: "))
    totalCoins = totalCoins + Balance
    print ('You now have a total Balance of' ,totalCoins ,'P')
    CoinAmount = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
while CoinAmount != "Yes":
    break
choice = int(input("Row 1 are crisps they cost 40p, Row 2 are drinks they cost 60p and Row 3 are sweets they cost £1 Choose a row: "))

if choice == 1:
    row1 = input("Please choose either A1, B1 or C1 for your item: ")
if row1 == "A1":
    print('You have bought A Packet of Walkers Crisps for 40p, you now have' , (totalCoins - 40), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 40
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row1 == "A2":
    print('You have bought a tube of Pringles for 40p, you now have' , (totalCoins - 40), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 40
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row1 == "A3":
    print('You have bought a packet of Lays for 40p, you now have' , (totalCoins - 40), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 40
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif choice == 1 and totalCoins < 40:
    print('You cannot buy anything else please take your change of:' ,Change ,'P')


if choice == 2:
    row2 = input("Please choose either A2, B2, C3 for your item: ")
elif row2 == "A2":
    print('You have bought a can of Diet Coke for 60p and you now have', (totalCoins - 60), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 60
    Credit = input ("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row2 == "B2":
    print('You have bought a bottle of Crystal Pepsi for 60p and you now have', (totalCoins - 60), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 60
    Credit = input ("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row2 == "C2":
    print('You have bought a bottle of Sprite for 60p and you now have', (totalCoins - 60), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 60
    Credit = input ("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif choice == 2 and totalCoins < 60:
    print ('You cannot buy this please choose something else')
    choice = int(input("Row 1 are crisps they cost 40p, Row 2 are drinks they cost 60p and Row 3 are sweets they cost £1 Choose a row: "))


if choice == 3:
    row3 = input("Please Choose Either A3, B3, and C3 for your item: ")
elif row3 == "A3":
    print('You have bought a bar of Cadburys Chocolate for £1 and now have' , (totalCoins - 100), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 100
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row3 == "B3":
    print('You have bought a packet of Strawberry Laces for £1 and now have' , (totalCoins - 100), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 100
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif row3 == "B3":
    print('You have bought a packet of Haribo for £1 and now have' , (totalCoins - 100), 'P left')
    Change = totalCoins - 100
    Credit = input("Would you like to continue, Type Yes to continue or No to stop ")
elif choice == 3 and totalCoins < 100:
    print("You cannot afford this please choose something else")
```

I have my rows in Python3 defined by an Input but if I for example decide to choose 3 for my Choice it then says that I have not defined row1 earlier on in my code.

I am not sure what I have not done to define it since it is using an input to classify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you haven't indented your code properly. Python code relies upon correct indentation to determine the order of processing for commands. Currently your code checks row1 value even if you didnt select row1, but you define row1 based on selecting it from the input. You need to indent the if statements under each choice selection like the following.

```
if choice == 1:
    row1 = input("Please choose either A1, B1 or C1 for your item: ")
    if row1 == "A1":
        //do something
    elif row1 == 'A2':
        //do something else etc...
```

Comment: You shouldnt be using elif after your "if choice" in 2 and 3, look at the way you did it for choice 1, change it to that, and follow the indentation above

Comment: Also you're not checking the money properly, its possible to buy things with no money. Remember, most languages drop out of if else statements the first true statement they find, so you should really check the money first.